# I'm struggling to create a button in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var buttonDivEl = document.getElementById('buttonDiv');
var startFunctionEl = document.getElementById('startFunction');

startFunctionEl.onclick = myFunction;

function myFunction() {
    startFunctionEl.remove();
    var createButton = document.createElement("button");
    createButton.innerHTML = "my new button";
    document.buttonDivEl.appendChild(createButton);
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonDiv"></div>
<button id="startFunction">Click</button>
```

My HTML is just a button (id of startFunction) inside of a div (id of buttonDiv)

I'm trying to make it so when I click the startFunction button, it will remove it and add a new button inside of buttonDiv, but it doesn't seem to be working properly. if I replace the following code:

```
document.buttonDivEl.appendChild(createButton);
```

with

```
document.body.appendChild(createButton);
```

it works, but I want it to append to the buttonDiv specifically, not the body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code from:

```js
document.buttonDivEl.appendChild(createButton);
```

To:

```js
buttonDivEl.appendChild(createButton);
```